# Responsive background image

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm trying to make a full screen responsive slideshow with Orbit ( foundation 5 ). I have problem with the background image, it's still fixed .

My code:

```
<ul class="example-orbit" data-orbit>
  <li class="slide slide1"></li>
  <li class="slide slide2"></li>
</ul>




html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
ul , li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.orbit-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.orbit-container ul,.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container>* {
  height: 100%; 
}

.slide {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
    .slide1 {
      background: url('image-url') no-repeat;
}

        .slide2 {
          background: url('image-url') no-repeat;
    }
```

How can i fix it ?

[DEMO](http://www.salmenbejaoui.com/test/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add background-size to the class where you set the backgrounds:

```
.slide1, .slide2 {
background-size:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
.orbit-container .slide {
    background-size: contain;
}
```

via the firebug console seemed to make it responsive.